# How to return an Object referenced by an ObjectInspector

Tags: java, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm writing a custom Hive UDF to parse key/value pairs in a Map according to the values defined in a properties file.  The format being validate(Map<String, String>, String).  The intent being to have the first argument be the Map to evaluate, and the second to contain the properties file.

The issue I'm having is that the GenericUDF class appears to expect both of these values to be dynamic for the query, as the initialize() function cast arguments as ObjectInspectors, which from the looks of things give no possible option to return the object they're inspecting.

I want the initialize function to load the properties file, and the evaluate function to return pass/fail.  This isn't nearly enough code to cover everything I've tried, but hopefully it gives someone who knows what they're doing a good idea of the issue:

```
public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
  mapOI = (MapObjectInspector) arguments[0];
  StringObjectInspector stringOI = (StringObjectInspector) arguments[1];

  try {
    // Begin Debug
    System.out.println(stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(((DeferredObject) arguments[1]).get()));
    // End Debug

    loadProperties(stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(((DeferredObject) arguments[1]).get()));
  }
  catch (HiveException exception) {
    throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(1, "Failed to cast properties file path for evaluation by loadProperties... What did you do?");
  }
```

Comment: what do you want to return?stringOI  or mapOI ?

Comment: Sorry, the code doesn't detail well enough, but I would like the string referenced by stringOI to be passed to another function.  At this point in my development I was trying to cast as the DeferredObject used by the evaluate function to retrieve the Ojbect, and was catching the HiveException and re-throwing as a UDFArgumentException to eat the compile error.  Edits incoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialize method is called only once and therefore the parameters can only be considered as metadata describing the the input types that the evaluate method expects to receive. Thus the only place where you can actually see the input values is in the evaluate method which is potentially called multiple times, usually once per row. You should really only use the initialize function to validate the types rather than the actual values. That is, in your case, check that the input is of type map with primitive-category elements of type string. Validation for the actual values should be carried out in the evaluate method.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I had come to a similar conclusion after looking at the implementations of UDFs like substr().  For the purpose of my solution I'm trying something dirty by setting a flag once the properties file is loaded to prevent multiple loads during evaluation.